# Restrict or change color of specific line in Vim

Tags: git, vim, git-commit, vim-syntax-highlighting

I use Vim for git commits. I have created a `.gitcommittemplate`:

```
############################### <BASLIK> ###############################
#
# ...
#
# |--En fazla 50 Karakter olabilir(Max 50 Char)--|
my real title

my real body
```

I want to restrict line 6 for 50 characters. Or even better, after 50 characters convert it to red and restrict writing after 72 characters.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the highlighting, try this:

```
highlight LineSix guifg=red ctermfg=red
syntax match LineSix /\%6l\%51c.*/
```

This creates a new highlight group named *LineSix*, and then sets it to be red in the GUI or in the terminal. Then it says *anything matching this regex is that highlight group*.

The regex uses some fun magic. Here's a break down:

```
\%6l
```

will match anything on line 6 (try `:h /\%l`)

```
\%51c
```

will match anything on column 51 (try `:h /\%c`)

and then obviously `.*` will match anything.

As for restricting more than 75 characters, I don't think this is possible. You can try setting `textwidth` and `colorcolumn`, but these don't *force* you to use less than 75 characters, and they won't apply to a single line.

Comment: Can I restrict this for only commit templates?

Comment: I have created a new file: .vim/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim  But it doesn't work